# Can I ground only part of my house?

Tags: electrical, gfci, grounding, old-house, old-work

**Background:**

My house was built in the 50s (I think) or thereabout. Hence the electrical wiring reflects the understanding of that time and is not the way that current (2023) code and safety regulations would have it be.

Specifically, there is no true ground for anything in the house (yes there are GFCI outlets in the kitchen and bathroom). Some or all of the outlets throughout the house are in metal boxes; those boxes aren't connected to the breaker panel or any outside grounding.

**Current situation:**

It is the case that digging through the floors and walls to run metal conduit to every outlet in the house would be time consuming and expensive (and, I expect, potentially dangerous).

That said, most or all of the wiring in the basement is easily accessible (only some goes through the floor to places where somebody can't get at it easily; the rest of it goes to outlets, lights, washer, and dryer).

**Possible upgrades:**

An electrician told me that the best thing to do in this situation is have all the breaker boxes switched out for GFCI breakers (and not worry about the lack of true grounding). Given what I know that sounds like a good idea.

I think it might also be possible to run a real ground wire to the outside and put the wires in the basement inside metal conduit.

**Question:**

Is there any point in having that done? Is there any good reason to try to real-ground only part of the house? Or does that have zero benefit over a GFCI breaker and I just shouldn't worry about the lack of grounding (except for the GFCI) in the basement or any other part of the house?

Comment: Are you in Chicago or some jurisdiction that requires metal conduit? It’s better in many ways, but not generally used.

Comment: I live in Rochester, NY. I don't know whether state code mandates metal conduit or not. Assuming that it doesn't, what's the best way to ground the electrics in my house? Is installing GFCI breakers really the only viable option?

Comment: I’m out of my depth, so I’ll let the real electricians jump in, but the obvious ones are: rewire with modern nm-b, add a separate ground wire, or protect with gfci.  Your electrician knows that rewiring from the basement isn’t trivial, which is probably why he likes breakers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can leave some circuits ungrounded and GFCI protected (either at the breaker or at the first outlet in the circuit).

And you can have proper grounded circuits in places where it is easier to achieve. and forego the GFCI protection in those places (unless there are other reasons to have it).

There are reasons to have proper grounding, some appliances require a real ground. Or if you ever want to tinker with electronics then you should ground yourself and your anti-static worksurface to avoid electrostatic discharge. If you have outlets that you know are grounded then you don't need to find other solutions.

Comment: Thank you for answering the questions that I actually posed. That's very helpful.